# When is it necessary to allocate dynamic memory using malloc on pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am having trouble fully understanding the malloc() function in C, more precisely when it is necessary to use it.

When I declare a pointer to a global struct like so,

```
struct Position* currentPositionPtr;
```

do I need to assign dynamic memory to it using malloc to initialize it? 
Or is it good practice to simply assign a pointer of the struct to it later on when needed like e.g.

```
currentPositionPtr = getPosition();
```

where `getPosition()` returns a pointer to the "struct Position".

Comment: Is this really asking when/why does one use dynamic memory allocation? It sounds like you already understand what `malloc` does. You might want to read this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

Comment: `malloc()` is usually used when you don't know how much of something or how many of something you need until you actually run the program (and there may not be a reasonable upper bound for a pre-allocation).

Comment: I realized that too, changed it to a hopefully a little better title.

Comment: @jxh ...aaaaaand you need the array/struct to survive function returns. It's 2013, there's no good reason **not** to use VLAs with automatic storage duration if there's no **real** need for dynamic allocation.

Comment: @H2CO3: For myself, I only use unbounded VLA to describe a pointer to an array. For temp memory for manipulation, I prefer to use a fixed length buffer that I am reasonably sure will work most of the time, and dynamically allocate if it is larger than that. This is just to prevent the stack from blowing up.

Comment: @jxh (and if you need temp buffers of 100000000 elements, then probably a code redesign would be nice, I must add.)

Comment: @H2CO3: Or track down the bug. But if your router has already crashed, then everyone is already ticked off at you. :-)

Comment: @H2CO3: As to surviving function returns, I prefer the method of the caller passing in the memory, and an explicit "creation" function to create the memory to be used by other functions if the type is opaque.

Comment: @jxh So does the C standard library, and probably you're both right. The reason I write constructors too that return mallocated pointers is that it's nice and readable. [(But there are counterexamples as well...)](https://github.com/H2CO3/libjsonz/blob/master/src/jsonz.c#L328)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What does `getPosition()` do?

If it returns a valid pointer to `struct Position`, then of course you don't need to allocate memory for the struct *twice.* I hope your function does **not** look like this:

```
struct Position *getPosition()
{
    struct Position p = { x, y };
    return &p;
}
```

since this would exhibit undefined behavior (by returning a pointer to a block scope automatic object). Generally, you rather return an **already** `malloc()`ated pointer instead:

```
struct Position *getPosition()
{
    struct Position *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    p->x = 42;
    p->y = 1337;
    return p;
}
```

Then, again, you don't need an **additional** call to `malloc()`.

If, however, it's not the called function who is responsible for the allocation, then, well... it's the caller who is:

```
void getPosition(struct Position *p)
{
    p->x = 42;
    p->y = 1337;
}
```

And in this latter case you would need to call it like this:

```
struct Position *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
getPosition(p);
```

if you need your struct to survive function returns, or

```
struct Position p;
getPosition(&p);
```

if you don't.

Comment: getPosition returns a valid pointer to a global struct Position (that's been initialized with some standard values before). So it makes perfect sense that I wouldn't have to allocate storage twice like you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` (or another memory-allocating function) is needed whenever you need the system to give memory to you.

So yes, when you do

```
struct Position* currentPositionPtr;
```

you will either need a call to `malloc()`:

```
currentPositionPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct Position));
```

or to assign the pointer to the address of an already allocated block of memory:

```
struct Position globalPos;

void func(void) {
    struct Position pos;
    struct Position* currentPositionPtr = &pos; //ok
    struct Position* globalPosPtr = &globalPos; //also ok
    ...
}
```

because all you are doing is declaring the pointer, not reserving space for a structure.

However, if your pointer is **global**, assigning it to stack-allocated memory is potentially dangerous. Consider the following:

```
struct Position *globalPosPtr = NULL;

void foo(void) {
    struct Position pos;
    globalPosPtr = &pos;
    //can dereference globalPosPtr with no problems here
    ...
}

void bar(void) {
    foo();
    //globalPosPtr is invalid here
    ...
}
```

As for your question about having another function that returns a pointer:

`getPosition()` will need to use `malloc` or some other memory-allocating function itself. So doing that is perfectly fine, and can make sense if you generally want to initialize values in the struct to some values. However, remember that, even if you called `malloc` inside some other function, you will need to `free` the memory when you are done using it to prevent memory leaks.

To answer the question in the title, whenever you declare something as a pointer, you need to give it something to point at if you want to use it. If you want it to point at a new thing, you need to dynamically allocate it with `malloc()` or a related function.

Comment: @Mike Exactly. For the very same reason, "`malloc` is needed whenever you need memory given to you" is false too.

Comment: Putting back my comment so H2CO3's makes sense: I don't like the way this is worded: "So yes, when you do
`struct Position* currentPositionPtr;` you will need a call to malloc() before using the pointer" because that statement *isn't* true. Having a pointer doesn't require you to use `malloc()`, it could simply be set to the address of a local variable on the stack.

Comment: I suppose in trying to make my answer be very simple for the asker, I oversimplified. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, `malloc` is used in these cases:

1. When you want to **allocate memory dynamically:** In other words, when you don't know how much memory you're going to need. Or when you don't know when you'll stop needing it.
2. When you want to **allocate a very large amount of memory:** The heap can grow very large, but the stack is much more constrained. Allocating something very large on the stack could lead to a stack overflow (*hey! That's the name of the site!*). Of course, such sizes are implementation specific, hence the rather subjective phrase "very large".
3. When you want your allocated memory to **be accessible externally:** If other threads of your program need access to a piece of memory, allocating it on the stack of one thread would be a bad idea, because it could be overwritten as that thread moves on, and then everyone else would be looking at corrupted memory.
4. Probably a couple of other cases too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already know how malloc works, but I'll try to answer your question.

Whenever you malloc, just be sure to keep a pointer on it so that you may manipulate it (or free it). The pros of malloc is that it is dynamic. Instead of declaring an array, you can declare a linked list of malloc'd structs (for example) and use pointers to keep track of them. In this way you never run into a problem such as walking off of the array. Instead you can just ask for more space dynamically and free it later when needed.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a struct with a known size, you dont have to use malloc to allocate the memory because memory is not changable between to different struct Position, however,

if within struct Position, you have a pointer to unknown size, depending on some user input, then you may use malloc to allocate that size of needed memory block.

also if you are allocating struct Position array, then

```
currentPositionPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct Position)*neededSize);
```

after you are done, you will have to delete the memory with

```
free (currentPositionPtr)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few simple things to understand :

1. malloc() simply returns you memory from heap and its the responsibility of the user process to FREE this chunk of memory by calling the FREE system call.
2. When at coding time you know, that you need to deal with fixed amount of memory say a struct ,an array  then you can satisfy the memory requirement of the process with local variables and Global Variables.

And from your query,it seems that you are confused when you have to deal with malloc and as a result pointers.

1. You need a pointer to hold the address of the memory allocated by malloc system call.
2. The pointer not necessarily  point to the memory allocated by malloc,it can be any valid memory like:

   ```
    int a =2;
    int *ptr; 
    ptr = &a;
   ```

So here, ptr points to memory location NOT allocated by malloc.

Conversely, you can do

```
   int *ptr;  
   ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

In your case a pointer currentPositionPtr to struct can point to the address of Global/local variable provided the memory address remains valid throughout the access of this pointer.

I hope this simplifies things.

Comment: currentPositionPtr points to a correctly initialized global variable of the type struct Position. The fact that it's a global variable guarantees that the memory address remains valid throughout the entire execution of the program, or am I mistaken here? Anyway, thanks for the explanation that did clarify a few things!

Comment: You are correct here,in your case as the currentPositionPtr pointer points to the global struct,it implies that pointer is valid till the global variable is valid simply.  But anyway you can access the global variable directly, why there is a need to access it via pointer?

Comment: The program is running on a STM32 microcontroller and I was under the impression that a pointer to a struct is more efficient than passing the entire struct by value. Well, but when I could access it directly without any function call it'd still be the fastest.. So yea in this case it would make more sense to access it directly, but I was confused with malloc in general, this was just an example.